How Can I use the navHost with Argument?
all.
I'm trying to create the navigate with Enums and arguments on Jetpack Compose, but it fails and have no idea, hope your advice.
enum list I made is below,
enum class CounterAppScreen(@StringRes val title: Int){
    MainScreen(title = R.string.main_screen),
    CountScreen(title = R.string.counter_screen)
}

And trying to go below composable with NavHost from Clickable Text.
            composable(
                "${CounterAppScreen.CountScreen.name}/{counterId}",
                arguments = listOf(
                    navArgument("counterId"){type = NavType.IntType}
                )
            )

                Text(
                    text = counterInfo.count.toString(),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .clickable {
                            navController.navigate("${CounterAppScreen.CountScreen.name}/${counterInfo.id}")
                        },
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.displayLarge
                )

but below error showns, and I have no idea what to do on next. Hope your helps.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.example.basiccounterapp.ui.CounterAppScreen.CountScreen/{counterId

I could solve this problem, but I couldn't find a way to keep using the "enum".
Maybe my steps are normal steps, but let me share my findings.

enum to object
I guess the same way may be available on enum too, but the code I referred was used the object, and I followed it.

Original enum:
    enum class CounterAppScreen(@StringRes val title: Int){
      MainScreen(title = R.string.main_screen),
      CountScreen(title = R.string.counter_screen)
    }

Changed to object format:
    object CounterNameArgs {
        const val MAIN_SCREEN_NAME = "Counter"
        const val COUNTER_SCREEN_NAME = "Count"
            const val COUNTER_SCREEN_ID = "counterId"
    }
    
    object CounterAppScreen{
        const val MAIN_SCREEN = MAIN_SCREEN_NAME
        const val COUNT_SCREEN = "$COUNTER_SCREEN_NAME/{$COUNTER_SCREEN_ID}"
    }


Modify the composable calling:
If need more complex things, I may need more customize on the composable() contents, but in this case, no need to customize. just apply the COUNT_SCREEN, but it contains the name and ID that I wanted to pass. counterId properly got from backStackEntry.

        composable(
            CounterAppScreen.COUNT_SCREEN
        ){backStackEntry->
            val route = backStackEntry.destination.route
            val counterId = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("counterId") ?: ""
            Log.d("CounterAppScreen", "CountScreen-counterId = $counterId")


modify the button configuration:
I put this clickable into the text, so the modifier is used as below.
I expect this format follows to COUNT_SCREEN format.

    modifier = Modifier
    .clickable {    
navController.navigate("${CounterNameArgs.COUNTER_SCREEN_NAME}/${counterInfo.id}")
     },

Thanks.
